# jQuery width(); not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I think I'm going crazy :).

In my js file I have:

```
alert( $('.element').width() );
```

it will alert "867"...Which is wrong.

In the Chrome or Firefox console i type:

```
$('.element').width();
```

It responds with 567. Which is correct.

Am I missing something here. Should I be doing this a different way. Cause the code in the js file is messing everyting up.

BTW the element does have a width and float set through CSS -- width: 80% and float: left. But the browser consoles still give me the right width.

Thanks.

Comment: yes. It is in the document.ready function

Comment: No to both of those. This is just ( <div class="element"></div> ) width a width set to 80% of the screen with CSS and I wan't to grab the pixel width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    alert( $('.element').width() );
});
```

Comment: try edit... Are you dynamically loading elements into the element after dom ready? Are there images inside the element?

Comment: So what the hell did I miss here cause that works perfect. :) I didn't realize that I needed to put that in the .load() vs .ready()...

Comment: When the dom is ready the html elements have completed being built in the dom. Images and other things load after the dom is ready. by putting it into window.load you wait until they are fully loaded before creating the next event. Here is some documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21204612/javascript-load-vs-ready-vs-domready-vs-domcontentloaded-events

Comment: Dope! Thanks for the fix, explanation, and link. Your awesome!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('.element').outerWidth();
```

Let me know if it helps

Comment: Same thing. The alert is showing the pixel size if it was 100% width. but the consoles show the proper width value at the 80% of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to work with properties thinking about padding and margin extra sizes. Commands like `innerWidth` take care about the padding of the element, but `outerWidth` corresponds to the size counting it's border (and if receive true their margin too).

Take a look at this topic already closed, i hope this must help you: [What is difference between width, innerWidth and outerWidth, height, innerHeight and outerHeight in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845027/what-is-difference-between-width-innerwidth-and-outerwidth-height-innerheight)

Comment: I had it set to alert( $('.element').innerWidth() ); first and it does the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

## Cause

The **.width()** method is subject to the browser's [reflow and repaint](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/#1_js_css_style_layout_paint_composite). The browser reflows and repaints the DOM objects during runtime. Visual changes to the HTML document also trigger reflow and repaint.

With these reasons, the `.width()` method will return a zero (`0`) value during browser states where reflow-and-repaint is still about to happen.

## Solution

Always call the `.width()` method after reflow-and-repaint.

## Common cases

#### Case #1. Document ready VS Window load

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // during this state, .width() is more likely equal to zero (0)
});
```

During the `$(document).ready`, DOM objects are ready to be manipulated. However, the browser is still doing reflow-and-repaint. Thus, there is a huge chance you will get `.width()` = `0`

```
$(window).load(function(){
    // during this state, .width() is more likely to have the right values
});
```

At `$(window).load`, DOM objects are ready to be manipulated and the browser is done with reflow and have repainted everything on the document.

#### Case #2. Hidden VS Shown

**HTML**

```
<div style="display:none">
    <button>Foo</button>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
// still hidden
$('button').width(); // 0

// now shown
$('div').show();
$('button').width(); // right value
```

Again, to fix the zero width issue, always call the `.width()` method after reflow-and-repaint.